# Unable to install old flutter project, facing this issues

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

`Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart:28:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/Users/sanke/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/package_info_plus_windows-2.1.0/lib/package_info_plus_windows.dart': The system cannot find the file specified.

import 'package:package_info_plus_windows/package_info_plus_windows.dart';
^
.dart_tool/flutter_build/dart_plugin_registrant.dart:215:9: Error: Undefined name 'PackageInfoWindows'.
PackageInfoWindows.registerWith();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/sanke/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/screenshot-1.3.0/lib/screenshot.dart:160:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'window'.
window: ui.window,
^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:68:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
RenderView({
^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
`

I have tried so many things like:- deleted (pubspec.lock) file, updated old plugins, updated old version of flutter and kotlin, made changes in gradle file.
Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.